# Integrating Flask with Matplotlib failed

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am working on my twitter sentiment analyzer project. I am using matplotlib to plot the responses. I want to create an user friendly Interface Page which would take the input (topics or tags) from users and would send it to the analyzer which would analyze them and generate the graph in matplotlib. I succeeded giving inputs from the terminal. But now after integrating with flask it is not working.

my main.py

```
import sys,tweepy,csv,re
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SentimentAnalysis:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets = []
        self.tweetText = []

    def DownloadData(self, topic, count):
        # authenticating
        consumerKey = 'CKEY'
        consumerSecret = 'CSEC'
        accessToken = 'ATOK'
        accessTokenSecret = 'ASEC'
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
        searchTerm = topic
        NoOfTerms = count

        # searching for tweets
        self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang = "en").items(NoOfTerms)

        # Open/create a file to append data to
        csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

        # Use csv writer
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)


        # creating some variables to store info
        polarity = 0
        positive = 0
        wpositive = 0
        spositive = 0
        negative = 0
        wnegative = 0
        snegative = 0
        neutral = 0


        # iterating through tweets fetched
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            #Append to temp so that we can store in csv later. I use encode UTF-8
            self.tweetText.append(self.cleanTweet(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))
            # print (tweet.text.translate(non_bmp_map))    #print tweet's text
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            # print(analysis.sentiment)  # print tweet's polarity
            polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity  # adding up polarities to find the average later

            if (analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0):  # adding reaction of how people are reacting to find average later
                neutral += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.3):
                wpositive += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0.3 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.6):
                positive += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0.6 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 1):
                spositive += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > -0.3 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0):
                wnegative += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > -0.6 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.3):
                negative += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > -1 and analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.6):
                snegative += 1


        # Write to csv and close csv file
        csvWriter.writerow(self.tweetText)
        csvFile.close()

        # finding average of how people are reacting
        positive = self.percentage(positive, NoOfTerms)
        wpositive = self.percentage(wpositive, NoOfTerms)
        spositive = self.percentage(spositive, NoOfTerms)
        negative = self.percentage(negative, NoOfTerms)
        wnegative = self.percentage(wnegative, NoOfTerms)
        snegative = self.percentage(snegative, NoOfTerms)
        neutral = self.percentage(neutral, NoOfTerms)

        # finding average reaction
        polarity = polarity / NoOfTerms

        # printing out data
        print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm + " by analyzing " + str(NoOfTerms) + " tweets.")
        print()
        print("General Report: ")

        if (polarity == 0):
            print("Neutral")
        elif (polarity > 0 and polarity <= 0.3):
            print("Weakly Positive")
        elif (polarity > 0.3 and polarity <= 0.6):
            print("Positive")
        elif (polarity > 0.6 and polarity <= 1):
            print("Strongly Positive")
        elif (polarity > -0.3 and polarity <= 0):
            print("Weakly Negative")
        elif (polarity > -0.6 and polarity <= -0.3):
            print("Negative")
        elif (polarity > -1 and polarity <= -0.6):
            print("Strongly Negative")

        print()
        print("Detailed Report: ")
        print(str(positive) + "% people thought it was positive")
        print(str(wpositive) + "% people thought it was weakly positive")
        print(str(spositive) + "% people thought it was strongly positive")
        print(str(negative) + "% people thought it was negative")
        print(str(wnegative) + "% people thought it was weakly negative")
        print(str(snegative) + "% people thought it was strongly negative")
        print(str(neutral) + "% people thought it was neutral")

        self.plotPieChart(positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, NoOfTerms)


    def cleanTweet(self, tweet):
        # Remove Links, Special Characters etc from tweet
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

    # function to calculate percentage
    def percentage(self, part, whole):
        temp = 100 * float(part) / float(whole)
        return format(temp, '.2f')

    def plotPieChart(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
        labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Weakly Positive [' + str(wpositive) + '%]','Strongly Positive [' + str(spositive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
                  'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]', 'Weakly Negative [' + str(wnegative) + '%]', 'Strongly Negative [' + str(snegative) + '%]']
        sizes = [positive, wpositive, spositive, neutral, negative, wnegative, snegative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen','lightgreen','darkgreen', 'gold', 'red','lightsalmon','darkred']
        patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
        plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
        plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm + ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

My app.py

```
from main import SentimentAnalysis
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

sa = SentimentAnalysis()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Parse form data    
        topic = request.form['topic']
        count = request.form['count']

        return sa.DownloadData(topic, count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now I am not getting any response at all. Can anyone tell where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You would like to make a specific class to get the data from some template..
For say, using wtforms...

```py
from flask import *
from wtforms import *

class getData(Form):

    topic = StringField('topic: ',[validators.Length(min= 1, max=20)])
    count = IntegerField('Number') #maybe I missed here something
```

render these fields into a template. Then you can get the datas.
by using:

```py
x = getData(request.form)

to = x.topic.data
```

or simply you do as described [here](https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/flask-framework/flask-framework-form-values)